# How to clear a form but still display one of its fields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, httpresponse

I'd like to submit a form F, clear its fields, but still display one of its fields. F submits to a view that renders the very template that first displayed it

To do so, I return a `HttpResponseRedirect` object instead of rendering a template with the request :

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = New_mini_url_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if (MiniUrl.objects.filter(url=form.cleaned_data['url']).count() == 0):
                code = form.cleaned_data['code']
                request.session["code"] = code
                [... stuff ...]

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(home))

            else:
                code = form.cleaned_data['code']
                request.session["code"] = code
                [... stuff ...]

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(home))
        else:
            return render(request, 'mini_url/home.html', locals())

    else:
        form = New_mini_url_form()
        return render(request, 'mini_url/home.html', locals())
```

and I have `{{ request.session.code}}` in my template

Here is an extracts of project/settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request"
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to see the `code` in one of the form field after you redirect to home page?

Comment: I'd like to display it in the template but not in the form. It's like : you want to shorten a URL so you enter your URL, you submit and then I want the form empty for a new submission and the template to display the shortened link from the view's computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `code` variable in the session. Then access it using `request.session.code` in your template.

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = New_mini_url_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if (MiniUrl.objects.filter(url=form.cleaned_data['url']).count() == 0):
                code = form.cleaned_data['code']
                request.session['code'] = code # set code in the session
                [... stuff ...]

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(home))

            else:
                code = form.cleaned_data['code']
                request.session['code'] = code # set code in the session
                [... stuff ...]

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(home))
        else:
            return render(request, 'mini_url/home.html', locals())

    else:
        form = New_mini_url_form()
        return render(request, 'mini_url/home.html', locals())
```

Then in your template, you can access `code` by:

```
{{request.session.code}} # display code in the template
```

You must include `django.core.context_processors.request` in the settings.

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  ...
  'django.core.context_processors.request', # will pass request in the template
  ...
)
```

From Django 1.7 docs on [request context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request):

> django.core.context_processors.request
>
> If TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contains this processor, every
>   RequestContext will contain a variable request, which is the current
>   HttpRequest. Note that this processor is not enabled by default;
>   you’ll have to activate it.

Comment: this will only work if form is not valid or method =! post, otherwise I return HttpResponseRedirect objects and they do not include the request, therefore not the request.session.code and the template won't display anything...

Comment: @VictorSmt, you are wrong. Regardless of whether you return a template or redirect user to some url, `{{request}}` variable will always be present in the template as long as you add it as a [`context processor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request). Note that this processor is not enabled by default; you’ll have to activate it.

Comment: @VictorSmt Please check if you are able to access it. I think you would be able to access the value of `code` in the template.

Comment: You do seem to be right but it still does not work... pleas see edit ; thanks!

Comment: @VictorSmt Did you try to print `{{request.session.code}}` in the template as `<p>{{request.session.code}}</p>` somewhere inside `<body>` tag?

Comment: alright my bad. it is solved. Small mistake from the settings.py.     ------THANK YOU RAHUL and OZGUR -----

Comment: Happy to help buddy! :)